# Is applying Mathematics inevitably a form of analogical reasoning?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

As mathematical models are abstractions, applying them in any context is inevitably an analogical reasoning.

Comment: If it's not analogical reasoning, what it is? Inductive? Abductive? Hypothetical deductive? Nomological?...